# Button press using modal dialog on Ipad

Tags: jquery, ipad, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

In my app I have a button which when clicked opens up a bootstrap modal dialog.

Now I know Ipad doesn't do click events, so I used the following code I found on a tutorial:

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent,
    event = (ua.match(/iPad/i)) ? "touchstart" : "click";

$("button#loginSignup").bind(event, function(e) {
    $('#dialogs').load('dialogs/login-signup.php', function(){
        $('#dialog').modal()
    });
})
```

But the problem is, is that when I press the button:

```
<button id="loginSignup" class="btn btn-primary full-width">Login or Signup</button>
```

The dialog slides in for the top and instantly goes back up again as if the close button was pressed.

How do I fix this error?

---

Some extra info. I have just noticed that if the button is positioned where the dialog lands i.e the dialog ends up coving the button, the dialog stays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did with:

```
$("button#loginSignup").bind(event, function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    $('#dialogs').load('dialogs/login-signup.php', function(){
        $('#dialog').modal() 
    });
})
```